# How to include a Project from a server into a Laravel sail docker image

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I am totally new to PHP / Laravel / Linux / composer / docker etc.
However I do have the task: go retrieve some code files from an internal server and make a docker container out of it. The project is written in PHP 7.1.3 and uses the Laravel framework.

I've copied the whole https folder from the server which I think contains everything I need.

I also was able to create the example app from the Laravel documentation and also I made a brand new Laravel project. However, is there any chance to "generate" a new project using all the code files I have right now?

I even have a composer.json and composer.lock file, which in my opinion should "list" every component I would need in my docker installation, right?

What also bugs me is that I can't even get the project working on my dev machine...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this step by step. But let me first answer some of your questions.

- If "https" folder contains similar folder structure like fresh Laravel installation, it is likely to be all of it. But we can not be sure about it.
- As far as i know there is no way to generate new project out of your files. First of all you need to know which Laravel version project uses. It must be stated at `composer.json`.
- In you composer.json file lists required packages for you project. When you install them this packages are installed folder called `vendor`

Here is my suggestions;

As you stated it seems you are very new about these topics if someone give these task to you its not a smart way to teach this kind of topics.

I think you have to start with running project in your local machine. If you get errors than ask them in a new question. Most likely you need database and you need to know running migrations seeds etc.

When you manage to run the project you can start dockerizing your project. If your project is build with newer versions of laravel you can easly use sail otherwise you can build own dockerfile or upgrade laravel to newer versions.

Your problem is too broad, i think you cannot find answers to such question.

Comment: Hi xuma,
first thanks for your answer. I think you already helped me. I think the laravel version of the project was 4. Tomorrow i will try and install this laravel version and get the project running. After this step i will try to upgrad to the latest version and then dockerize it. maybe i was trying to many steps at once today. Thanks!